# Loading styles with style-loader into secondary windows

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron, webpack-style-loader

I have a project that uses electron and react. Styles in this project are defined in .scss files, which are then imported into react components (e.g. the main page, App.tsx, has an `import 'styles/main.scss'` statement).

Somewhere in the project I want to use a new window to act as a popup, and I do it like this:

```
const $div = document.createElement("div");
const wnd = window.open("", type, title);

// (...)

wnd.document.body.appendChild($div);

return createPortal(children, $div);
```

The way this new window behaves is customized in main.ts (the entry point for electron), like this:

```
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((args) => {
    return {
        action: "allow",
        overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
            frame: true,
            parent: mainWindow,
            minWidth: 400,
            minHeight: 400,
            // (...)
        } as BrowserWindowConstructorOptions
    }
});
```

As it is now, the new window won't have any styles injected to it, not even the styles imported directly by components placed in that window. I know that manually creating a `<link href="style.css" />` node is an option but that defeats the purpose of using style-loader, so I'd like to know if there's something I can set up in electron so child windows keep the main window's stylesheet.

What I wrote above.